# BluemixのSQL Databaseのページサイズ

Tags: bluemix

BluemixのSQL Databaseのページサイズを教えてください。表設計するため1ページのサイズを知りたいのですが、資料などに記述を見つけられませんでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

プランによって異なるようです。
Free Betaの場合は8KB/page、Smallの場合は4KB/pageです。